# Problemas com pip install para instalar o VirtualEnvWrapper no Windows

Tags: pip, python

Estou tentando instalar o `virtualenvwrapper` para, em seguida, instalar o Django.
Para isso, instalei o `pip`, mas sempre que tento executar no CMD:

```
pip install virtualenvwrapper-win
```

Aparece o erro:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenvwrapper-win

Estou usando a versão 3.6 do Python, 10.0 do pip e Windows.

Comment: O `pip` esta conseguindo instalar outros pacotes?

Comment: Aparece algum erro de certificado, poderia colocar a mensagem de erro toda por favor.

Comment: Então, tudo o que eu tentei instalar com o pip não instalou, porém, quando digito pip no cmd aparece a lista de comandos, o que significa que está funcionando.

Comment: Então se nada instala pode ser problema no requirements.txt ou no IPV6 ou nos certificados SSL do seu Windows, eu vou tentar formular uma resposta, talvez eu consiga ajudar.

Comment: Mariana fora o erro que vc citou aparece mais algum erro?

Comment: Não, é sempre o mesmo erro.

Comment: Agora pouco tava tentando seguir as instruções desse site, embora sem sucesso: https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/install-python-django-on-windows/

Comment: Não quis dizer erro diferente em ocasião diferente, pergunto se aparece detalhes abaixo ou acima do erro no CMD, geralmente depois da frase `<from versions:>`. Tem certeza mesmo que não aparece mais nada?

Comment: Aparece Collecting virtualenv

Comment: Não é problema com o Django, eu já citei os possiveis problemas, esse link não ajuda em nada, o problema pode ser em uma coisa totalmente não relacionada ao PIP e ao Python, se fosse no certeza que era no Django ou no virtualenv eu não teria falado das outras possibilidades. Entende? Por isto preciso de detalhes.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61614/discussion-between-mariana-ferreira-and-guilherme-nascimento).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como eu já disse, não adianta o pessoal vir chutando respostas, **este erro é genérico**, pode ser qualquer coisa e geralmente não é problema com o pacote (a não ser que o pacote não existe), isso não se resolve baixando manualmente o pacote e instalando da máquina local, veja que consegui instalar normalmente o `virtualenvwrapper` o pacote está correto:

[image: instalação]

Não tem nada haver com pacote errado como dito na outra resposta, tentar instalar o `pip install virtualenv` não vai funcionar, não é problema de dependências.

**A solução** é resolver o problema da rede, proxy ou SSL (seja lá qual for).

Como eu já disse, esse erro é **genérico** e pode ser qualquer coisa, então **o caminho ideal** é olhar o logs e detalhes para ter certeza, como solicitei para a Mariana, o erro detalhado é este:

```
C:\Users\u516709>pip install virtualenv 
Collecting virtualenv 
Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages. 
urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0380FC50>: Failed to esta 
blish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv 
/ 
Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages. 
urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0380FC90>: Failed to esta 
blish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv 
/ 
Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages. 
urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0380FA50>: Failed to esta 
blish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv 
/ 
Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages. 
urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0380FC30>: Failed to esta 
blish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv 
/ 
Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) 
after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages. 
urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x037FF930>: Failed to esta 
blish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed',)': /simple/virtualenv 
/ 
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement virtualenv (from versi 
ons: ) 
No matching distribution found for virtualenv
```

Logo na mensagem:

```
'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.requests.packages. 
    urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x0380FC50>: Failed to esta 
    blish a new connection: [Errno 11004] getaddrinfo failed'
```

Já dá para notar que o erro ou é com:

- A rede fora do computador está bloqueada ou usando algum proxy (como disse fora do computador) e só o administrador da rede pode resolver
- Rede está com algum conflito com IPV6
- Certificados SSL faltando (pouco provável)

### Se estiver usando HTTP proxy

Se a rede que você usa tiver algum bloqueio por proxy, o que é comum em empresas, será necessário configurar autenticação com proxy, para isto você terá que solicitar com o administrador os dados da autenticação (geralmente o computador já tem estes dados nas opções da Rede/Internet Explorer).

Então com os dados de autenticação do proxy você pode configurar nas variáveis de ambiente a autenticação do proxy com a variável `http_proxy` na "Variáveis de ambiente":

```
http_proxy=http://userid:pswd@proxyurl.com:port
```

e HTTPS:

```
https_proxy=http://userid:pswd@proxyurl.com:port
```

Para adicionar nas "Variáveis de ambiente" siga o passo a passo:

- Clique com o direito do Mouse no Meu Computador (ou Computar)
- Vá em Propriedades
- Configurações avançadas do sistema / Propriedades do sistema
- Clique no botão no final da janela chamado "Variáveis de ambiente"
- Vai aparecer dois campos selecione o de baixo aonde a "label" também diz "Variáveis de ambiente"
- Clique no botão `Novo...` e adicione a variável `http_proxy` com o valor do teu proxy `http://userid:pswd@proxyurl.com:port`
- Faça o mesmo novamente mas adicione o proxy para HTTPS `https_proxy` (não sei se é o mesmo, depende da rede da sua empresa)

Só pra constar, dependendo do proxy talvez não suporte HTTPS, então terá que entrar em contato com o administrador da rede.

Comment: Resposta muito completa e bem explicada. Embora não tenha resolvido pra mim, com certeza vai resolver pra alguém com o mesmo problema. :)

Comment: @MarianaFerreira não precisa marcar como aceita ainda, por favor vamos tentar ver qual o seu problema? Se tiver um tempo no domingo a tarde podemos conversar no chat e fazer os testes ;)

Comment: Então, o problema acontece aqui no computador de onde eu trabalho e domingo não estou trabalhando. Mas posso tentar instalar no meu notebook no domingo e ver se acontece o mesmo. Mas como o problema é de rede, não sei se ajuda muito. :/

Comment: @MarianaFerreira tem proxy no seu trabalho? Outra possibilidade é algum firewall, na maquina ou na rede

Comment: Eu vi pelas configurações aqui que tem proxy sim, tentei configurar mas não deu certo, fui até o DTI mas eles não estão muito dispostos a me ajudar.

Comment: @MarianaFerreira acho que eu consigo te ajudar, só preciso terminar algumas coisas e te chamo lá no chat

Comment: Ah, certo. Muito obrigada.

Comment: Não vai mais precisar. Vou ter que usar outra linguagem para o meu sistema. As regras da empresa não me permitem usar o Django por liberação de proxy.

Answer (score -2):

Tente:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Funcionou aqui

Comment: Tem certeza https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win ?

Comment: **Só pra constar**, eu não instalei o VirtualEnv em minha máquina e consegui instalar o Wrapper tranquilamente: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAq7t.png, então o problema não é com falta de dependências e sim com outra coisa.

Comment: Então, deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: O problema não está no pacote, então isso não responde a pergunta.

Answer (score -2):

O problema está no nome do módulo.

Utilize:

```
pip install virtualenv
```

Documentação de instalação do virtualenv, em inglês:
https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/installation/

Comment: Tem certeza https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenvwrapper-win ?

Comment: Pela necessidade que ele descreve, apenas virtualenv é o que ele precisa.

Comment: virtualenvwrapper é um wrapper para window. Mas só comentei mesmo porque talvez seja um problema com o requirements.txt ou com IPV6.

Comment: Exato. O que eu entendo é que ele precisa do virtualenv, mas deve ter procurado no Google como instalar e acabou achando o wrapper.

Comment: Não entendeu, tudo bem pode ser falta do virtualenv como dependencia, mas esse erro eventualmente é comum com outros pacotes, geralmente causado por outras falhas, é bem possivel que o virtualenvwrapper precise do virtualenv para rodar, mas não sei se é necessário para instalar, afinal de contas ele é só um "facilitador", mas nem vou entrar em detalhes, aguardemos.

Comment: **Só pra constar**, eu não instalei o VirtualEnv em minha máquina e consegui instalar o Wrapper tranquilamente: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lAq7t.png, então o problema não é com falta de dependências e sim com outra coisa.

Comment: Deu o mesmo erro.

Comment: Tente baixar o arquivo [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/packages/6f/86/3dc328ee7b1a6419ebfac7896d882fba83c48e3561d22ddddf38294d3e83/virtualenv-15.1.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl#md5=aa7e5b86cc8cdb99794c4b99e8d670f3). Então vá até a pasta onde baixou e use o `pip install nome_do_arquivo`.

Comment: O problema não está no pacote, então isso não responde a pergunta.